# Error in OrElseThrow when using within forEach

Tags: java, spring-boot, lambda, java-8, option-type

I need to use the OrElseThrow from within a forEach Loop.

Here's my Code:-

Service.java

```
    public SubscriptionPack saveSubscriptionPack(SubscriptionPack subscriptionPack)
            throws LuciVisionApplicationServiceException {
        if (subscriptionPackRepository.findByName(subscriptionPack.getName()).isPresent()) {
            throw new SubscriptionPackAlreadyExistsException("Subscription Pack With THe Given name 
             Already Exists");
        } else {
            List<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<>();
            float price = 0;
            subscriptionPack.getChannels().forEach(i -> {
                // Error Here saying "Unhandled exception type ChannelDoesNotExistException" and 
                // asking to surround with try Catch but OrElseThrow should have handled it
                Channel ch = channelRepository.findByName(i.getName())
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new ChannelDoesNotExistException("Channel With Given Name 
                         Does Not Exist"));
                channels.add(ch);
            });
            return new SubscriptionPack(subscriptionPack.getName(), null, channels);
        }

    }
```

If i use the normal for loop, it Works as expected. Why does this not work for java-8 for Each loop?

PS: My Repository is returning Optional.

Comment: `ChannelDoesNotExistException` seems to be a checked exception, and lambdas (in forEach()) typically mustn't throw a checked exception.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-exceptions

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Are you getting an error? An unexpected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet the current exception class structure is:

```
class LuciVisionApplicationServiceException extends Exception {}
class ChannelDoesNotExistException extends LuciVisionApplicationServiceException {}
```

There are two solutions, both of them result in [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html):

1. `ChannelDoesNotExistException` must extend `LuciVisionApplicationServiceException` which must be subtype of `RuntimeException`
2. `ChannelDoesNotExistException` must be subtype of `RuntimeException` itself.

The reason behind is simple. Since the traditional for-loop is a part of the procedural code inside the method, the exception is thrown immediately at the method level as excepted. If you use the `forEach` with a lambda expression, it is translated as anonymous class [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) which doesn't throw an exception on the method level ([`Consumer::accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-)), therefore your construct is impossible unless an instance of [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) is used:

```
subscriptionPack.getChannels().forEach(
    new Consumer<Channel>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(final Channel i) {    // no throwing exception singature

        }
    }
);
```

Further explanation at [JLS §11.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3) (emphasis mine):

> It is a *compile-time* error if a lambda body can throw some exception class `E` when `E` is a checked exception class and E is not a subclass of some class declared in the throws clause of the function type targeted by the lambda expression.

Comment: Makes sense, Thanks. And yes your illustrated Exception hierarchy is the one I have used in my application.